# How do I add lines while sharing?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, social-media

How do I add lines to:

```xml
<ons-button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Line1')">Share</ons-button>
```

I am trying to share a poem:

```
 Darkest night 
Longest flight
```

But while sharing it's submitting as:

> darkest night longest flight

What should I add in the to retain the new-lines in the share content?

Comment: Try to add \n character.

Comment: like? can u write in details...

Comment: When writing a file in text mode, '\n' is transparently translated to the native newline sequence used by the system, which may be longer than one character. When reading in text mode, the native newline sequence is translated back to '\n'.

Answer (score 4):

while writing use

> \n

to create line

Example

```
darkest night\nlongest flight
```

Which will out put

```
Darkest Night
Longest Flight
```